# validation of password field using a compare to string method or using an == but both not working

Tags: javascript, string

iam trying to validate the password field with the re-type password field but its not working :

```
function Signup() {

    alert('step one')
    var q=SignUppasswordField.val();
    var z=SignUpRetypepasswordField.val();

    if(q.toString()==z.toString()){

        alert('valid')
        var name= $('#SignUpName').val();
        var UserName=$('#SignUpUserName').val();
        var UserPassword=$('#SignUppasswordField').val();
        var EmailAddress=$('#SignUpEmail').val();
        callServer('successAdd','checkConnection',false,'addMember.php',{name:name,UserName:UserName,UserPassword:UserPassword,EmailAddress:EmailAddress});
    }

    else {

        alert('not valid');
        alert("please check entered info.")
    }

}
```

Comment: log the q and z value to see what are they.

Comment: the problem is in the compare function not in the values its not going into the if statement

Comment: Assuming `SignUppasswordField` and `SignupRetypepasswordField` are two text input fields, jQuery's `val()` will return a `string`. You don't need to use `toString()`. But besides that point, the code here looks ok. How is it not working?

Comment: did you mean the q.toString() == z.toString() failed? I think they are not equal, so failed. That is why I want to see what is the value for them.

Comment: Noman i have no idea, and xwhyLike if its failing it should move onto the else statement but its not doing that

Comment: So are you saying you are seeing  "step one" alert, but not any other alerts?

Comment: yes i tried "=="  "="  "q.eduals(z)" "q.compareTo(z)" nothing worked

Comment: JavaScript doesn't just stop execution unless if there was an Uncaught exception. Are there any errors being printed out in your javascript console?

Comment: no errors i even ran an alert on javascript ready to make sure that its all ready

Comment: What *are* the values of `q` and `z` when you test? Please do what @xwhyLikeThis suggested and log/alert them out. Or make a live example on jsFiddle for me to look at.

Comment: Maybe this is a typo? Does your `var q=SignUppasswordField.val();` need to be `var q=SignUpPasswordField.val(); //Capitalized the P` Maybe this is returning undefined or null and your other variable is a good string and therefore not returning true for the condition in your if statement? Maybe if you could show us your HTML we could get a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to use JQuery selector when assigning q and z using JQuery val()
Or put another way, val() is not defined for HTML DOM ELEMENT

```
var q=$('#SignUppasswordField').val();
var z=$('#SignUpRetypepasswordField').val();
```